# Need suggestion on DB architecture

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, ruby-on-rails-4

I am working on a Project where I have below use case.

User can have many taglines for them , we have lot of predefined data in the DB which we using to show autosuggestion when they started typing tag lines, I am using Rails.

```
User has_and_belongs_to_many taglines

Tagline has_and_belongs_to_many users
```

I have separate joint table and everything was fine , but now I need to store custom taglines of user to DB , which will be belongs to only particular user.

Should I clone the taglines table and add user ID to it Or what is the best architecture to handle these kind of scenario , if we have more than one model which have same use case as like taglines.

Comment: I would probably add a column `custom` to you `taglines` table, and use it to filter tags for suggestions.

Comment: @BroiSatse But taglines table is currently many-to-many , but the custom user taglines are belongs_to only user, why we need to mix both.?

Comment: If you create a second table, you will need to remember to update two tables/models every time you will want to change your model. You won;t be able to pull all the user tags in one go neither. `many-to-many` is able to hold `one-to-many` association. Just add a validation to check that given tag can belong to only one user if it is custom.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BroiSatse Comment make sense, I followed same.

> If you create a second table, you will need to remember to update two
>   tables/models every time you will want to change your model. You won;t
>   be able to pull all the user tags in one go neither. many-to-many is
>   able to hold one-to-many association. Just add a validation to check
>   that given tag can belong to only one user if it is custom.

Answer (score 0):

your existing *user* and *tagline* table has many-to-many relationship, keep it that way. Whereas the *user* table and the new *customTagline* has a one-to-many relationship so why don't you create a new table to represent it? Since you mentioned the *customTagline* belongs to only a particular user.

Comment: Thats very direct way , if I have only tagline your suggestion is good, but I have around 6 models which falls under same scenario , here I need to create 6 new models with same structure , is that advisable?

Comment: If you are not sure, that means you do not have enough data to make a decision. Which means any options is good given the current circumstances so just create the tables and code away. As you roll your code, you will gain more insight to the requirements and that is the time you will come back to refactor/normalize/denormalize the tables. This is how I would do it. @Senthil